# ng-change not applying changes to scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="guestName1" >
<input type="text" ng-model="guestName2" >

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="copy" ng-change="copyDetails()"> Check this to copy
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.copyDetails = function(){
    if($scope.copy){
        $scope.guestName2 = $scope.guestName1;
    else{
         $scope.guestName1 = undefined;
         $scope.guestName2 = undefined;
    }
    }
```

}

But If I type something in guestName1 and mark the checkbox as true, I do not see it copied to guestName2

Comment: Is that the actual JavaScript that you're using in your controller? Because there is a syntax error in the snippet..

Answer (score 0):

I guess above logic is working fine.

Check out this sample plunker code: [http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:FrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl%3aFrTqqTNoY8BEfHs9bB0f?p=preview)

I guess there is a typo in the code you have provided. The if loop does not have a closing brace or it is misplaced down?